# Load local data files to Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I just wondering that is it possible to load local data files(like .xlsx or .csv files that on my google drive) into Colaboratory?

Comment: as on 1/4/2020 drive has been replaced by "backup and sync".

Answer (score 47):

I was a bit confused by the example for loading local files on first glance as there was no place to specify a file path. All you need to do is copy and paste the [recipe](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c) to figure this out, but to be clear:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

will open an upload dialogue window where you can browse and select your local files for upload.

Then

```
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

will show you the keys to access what you just uploaded.

Edit for additional clarification: The dictionary `uploaded` will have keys of the selected filenames - so if for example you select a file `my_test.txt`, then you would access that file using `uploaded['my_test.txt']`.

Comment: @elphz  What happends if the file is an image?

Comment: but how do you load the file with Python afterward? I can't find a single example for that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as ivan_billan.  No problem 'uploading' but then there are no actual examples of how to access the uploaded file afterwards

Comment: The file can be accessed via `uploaded`, which is a Python dictionary. For example, if you selected a file named 'test.txt', then `uploaded['test.txt']` will give you the Python object. You can use `type` to see that you have uploaded a string. Just printing `uploaded.keys()` will show you all of the filenames.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez - I just tested with a png file, and it looks like it still uploads as a byte string

Answer (score 19):

First, executing this cell should create an inline "Choose Files" button

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

After selecting your file(s), `uploaded` will be a dictionary of keys (the file names) and values (the encoded file objects).  To decode the files for a library such as Pandas, try

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['filename.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
```

After this your dataframe `df` should be ready to go

Comment: I just ran the import and "files.upload()" line but it is taking forever. What does it actually do? Is it going to upload every files in my google drive?

Comment: @kawingkelvin If I remember correctly, It should cause a file-selection window to pop up over your notebook.  From there you click the files you want.  If it's not loading up, maybe something in your browser is preventing the pop-up

Comment: I figured out whats wrong and how it's supposed to work, after switching from safari to chrome (FF doesnt work either). it looks like google colab is not friendly to other browsers other than chrome.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've got this error: `KeyError: '/path/to/my_file.csv'`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, all of these scenarios are supported.

For recipes to access local and Drive files, check out the [I/O example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb).

For access to `xls` files, you'll want to upload the file to Google Sheets. Then, you can use the `gspread` recipes in the same [I/O example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb).

A recently added way to upload local files is to use the 'Files' tab in the right hand side drawer.

[image]

From there, you can upload a local file using the 'upload' button.

[image]

(You can also download files by right clicking on them in the file tree.)

Comment: For some reason, this wont get updated even if you delete the files in the panel. so, its better to use ls to know about the present situation

Comment: Is there any way for that Files tab to come with a certain csv? As in, is there anyway that if I share a collaboratory project with someone, once it is done loading completely, they have the same csv I have (without needing to upload manually each time)

Answer (score 10):

To load local data files to Colab:

**Method 1: Google Drive Method**

1. Upload data file from system memory to Google drive.
2. Mount Google drive in Colab

   `from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`
3. Then-> `path = "/gdrive/My Drive/filename"`

You can now access google drive files in Google Colab.

**Method 2: Direct Load**

```
from google.colab import files
def getLocalFiles():
    _files = files.upload()
    if len(_files) >0:
       for k,v in _files.items():
         open(k,'wb').write(v)
getLocalFiles()
```

**Method 3: Using import files**

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Comment: In the Method 1, you gave the instruction how to connect Google Drive, but not about how to read a file (a .csv for example). You create a variable called "path", but then what do you do with it? How do you upload your .csv from you Google Drive into the Google Colab notebook?

Comment: Once you are connected to drive. Pretty straight forward use pandas. pd.read_csv('/gdrive/My Drive/temp.csv')

Answer (score 5):

It's a 2 step process.

Step 1 : First invoke a file selector with in your colab notebook with the following code

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

this will take you to a file browser window

step 2 : To load the content of the file into Pandas dataframe, use the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['iris.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
print(df)
```

Comment: You should always format your code using the {} button or CTRL-K.

Answer (score 4):

Putting this out there as an alternative for people who prefer another way to upload more files - this basically allows you to upload your files through Google Drive.

Run the below code (found this somewhere previously but I can't find the source again - credits to whoever wrote it!):

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass

!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

Click on the first link that comes up which will prompt you to sign in to Google; after that another will appear which will ask for permission to access to your Google Drive.

Then, run this which creates a directory named 'drive', and links your Google Drive to it:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

If you do a `!ls` now, there will be a directory `drive`, and if you do a `!ls drive` you can see all the contents of your Google Drive.

So for example, if I save my file called `abc.txt` in a folder called `ColabNotebooks` in my Google Drive, I can now access it via a path `drive/ColabNotebooks/abc.txt`

Comment: For the missing source -- that looks like the bit of code at: https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d#c890

Answer (score 4):

To get data from your system to colab try this:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Choose the file you want to upload and hit enter and its done.
For example, I have uploaded an image and displayed it using the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img_cvt = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(img_cvt)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Say, You have a folder on your Google drive named `Colab` and a `csv` is file located there.
To load this file

```
import pandas as pd
titanic = pd.read_csv(“drive/Colab/Titanic.csv”)
titanic.head(5)
```

**Before that, you may need to run these command:**

Run these codes first in order to install the necessary libraries and perform authorization.

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

When you run the code above, you should see a result like this:
[image]

Click the link, copy verification code and paste it to text box.

After completion of the authorization process,

mount your Google Drive:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL for uploading your files in Google Colab:

```
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c
```

go to `Local file system>Downloading files to your local file system`
Then run the code. After that, browser button will be appeared for you to uploading your files from your PC.