# How to upload and save large data to Google Colaboratory from local drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have downloaded large image training data as zip from this Kaggle link

https://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-restaurant-photo-classification/data

How do I efficiently achieve the following?

1. Create a project folder in Google Colaboratory
2. Upload zip file to project folder
3. unzip the files

Thanks

EDIT: I tried the below code but its crashing for my large zip file. Is there a better/efficient way to do this where I can just specify the location of the file in local drive?

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
!pip install kaggle
api_token = {"username":"USERNAME","key":"API_KEY"}
import json
import zipfile
import os
with open('/content/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)
!chmod 600 /content/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle config set -n path -v /content
!kaggle competitions download -c jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge
os.chdir('/content/competitions/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge')
for file in os.listdir():
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()
```

There is minor change on *line 9*, without which was encountering error.
source: https://gist.github.com/jayspeidell/d10b84b8d3da52df723beacc5b15cb27
couldn't add as comment cause rep.

Answer (score 2):

You may refer with these threads:

- [Import data into Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986398/import-data-into-google-colaboratory)
- [Load local data files to Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320052/load-local-data-files-to-colaboratory)

Also check out the [I/O example notebook](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb). Example, for access to `xls` files, you'll want to upload the file to Google Sheets. Then, you can use the `gspread` recipes in the same I/O example notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `kaggle-cli` module to help with the download.

It’s discussed in [this fast.ai thread](http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-to-download-data-for-lesson-2-from-kaggle-for-planet-competition/7684).

Comment: +! Is there something similar available for topcoder.com?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this script that downloads and extracts data from the Kaggle API to a Colab notebook. You just need to paste in your username, API key, and competition name.

https://gist.github.com/jayspeidell/d10b84b8d3da52df723beacc5b15cb27

The manual upload function in Colab is kind of buggy now, and it's better to download files via wget or an API service anyway because you start with a fresh VM each time you open the notebook. This way the data will download automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to upload the data to dropbox (if it can fit), get a download link. Then in the notebook do

```
!wget link -0 new-name && ls
```