pandas cannot find local csv file in google colab
I tried to open a csv file in google colab that I downloaded from the internet and it's in my download file. The full path is:
C:\Users\Asus\Downloads

so I looked on the internet and it said to change the backslash into a double backslashes or a forward slashes or a raw string, so I tried all of the below:
filepath = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\Data.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(filepath)
dataset

filepath = "C:/Users/Asus/Downloads/Data.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(filepath)
dataset

filepath = r"C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Data.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(filepath)
dataset

But I always get the error:
NotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\Data.csv'

even though I copied the filepath

what is the exact error statement?

are you sure the filepath is definitely correct, and the filename exactly matches (inc capital letter etc).  It's really easy to introduce a typo somewhere and then the file can't be found

try if os.path.exists(file_path):     print("File exists")  It is very likely that your path is not right

NotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Data.csv'
this is the error statement

are you running the 3 variants in the same file or jn cell?

im running the code on jn cell

There is nothing wrong with your code, so it must be an issue with the file path or file name not being quite right.  The file you're trying to open is definitely in your downloads? and definitely called Data.csv?

yeah its in my download file and its called Data.csv. I tried moving the file in my desktop and create a new folder so it has different filepath and it still shows the same error

What's your current working directory? I don't think it should make a difference, but maybe? You can find this by running import os and then os.getcwd()

You run your script locally and not in some online interpreter, right?

what is an online interpreter? sorry for asking

@Bramantyo Adji short: a website where you can write code and execute it without installing anything on your pc.

im using my previous directory and it still shows

im using google colab, does that make any difference?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198405/how-to-use-google-colab-to-work-with-local-files

> import os import pandas as pd
> 
> filepath = r"C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\Data.csv"
> 
> # Check if the file exists if os.path.isfile(filepath):
>     print("File exists")
>     try:
>         dataset = pd.read_csv(filepath)
>         print(dataset)
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(f"Error reading the file: {e}") else:
>     print("File does not exist")

