# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am getting this error everytime running python code on local data from my drive 
I am using the code below to import the data from my drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: Does that directory exist on your machine?

Answer (score 28):

Check if your file exists in this "/content/drive/" location

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/")
!ls
```

Most likely it would be under 'My Drive'

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive")
!ls
```

Comment: This also resolves issue of FileNotFound: "/content/drive/My" because of the space between My and Drive.

Comment: doesn't work for me either, I simply get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/'. Are you sure it meant to work under Windows?

Comment: Eli, it can work under windows when you use regex. for example, it can be os.chdir(r"/cotent/drive/My Drive"). this threw away the error raised by the space between My and Drive.

Answer (score 8):

First, check the path. Make sure the file exists in the right path.

## How to make that sure?

Simple. Just use terminal code like this example of mine:

> `! ls /content/drive/My\ Drive/data/sahamyab`
>
> colabs respons: `data.jl  sahamyab.zip  tweets.json`

If your file is not on that path, then you are in the wrong way. Otherwise, after you see that the file exists, just open it like this:

`open("/content/drive/My Drive/data/sahamyab/tweets.json")`

**WARNING:** look at paths carefully. The first one has `My\ Drive` and the second `My Drive`. because the first one is on the terminal path and space is `\`  but the second one is in the python path.

Answer (score 2):

google has changed to Mydrive and deleted space. so no "My Drive" but "MyDrive
os.chdir('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/iss/vse/data/')

Answer (score 1):

```
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive')
ls
```

to check whether the file exists

try to avoid spaces when you are creating new directories inside the drive cos it can lead to compile-time errors

If you just want to mount your drive to the colab you can do that without any code using the web IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting above and to find and load local data files in Google Colab:

1. Upload data file from your system memory to Google drive:
2. Mount Google drive in Colab:
   2.1) Import at your code: *from google.colab import drive*
   2.2) mount the directory where is the data at google drive: *drive.mount('/content/gdrive')*
   2.3) To mount the directory, it will be required authorization for your google account
3. *path = "/gdrive/My Drive/filename"*

> Reference:
> [Load local data files to Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320052/load-local-data-files-to-colaboratory)

Answer (score 1):

I came over the issue when I used regex as follows.
You may also want to try it.

```
import os
os.chdir(r"/content/drive/My Drive")
```

Note the position of r, for regex

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me it was that "drive" needs to be spelled with an r as "driver".
"My Drive" including the space worked for me as well.

```py
os.chdir('/content/driver/My Drive/*filename*/')
```

Answer (score 0):

to run a python file in the Google Drive;

```
!python3 /content/drive/My\ Drive/data/file.py
```