# (Python)Unable to import excel file using colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

i have tried to import an excel csv file from my local disk but failed

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/da/SeoulBikeData.csv',encoding="gbk")
print("df")
```

error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/da/SeoulBikeData.csv'
```

Comment: Does **SeoulBikeData.csv** exists provided location?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i think yes , i have downloaded and place it in that location

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320052/load-local-data-files-to-colaboratory.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to load file into local directory of colab
[image]

here you can click on that folder
[image]

Click on icon of upload and upload the file you want to read

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'fummy.csv',encoding="gbk")
df
```

Finally your file will be loaded.
[image]

But there is limitation whenever you close your notebook on colab you have to done whole process again
better way to do this is upload file on drive and mount the drive and load file from drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After that:

```
df= pd.read_csv("copy path file here")
```

Third Way to load file in google colab is:

```
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['fummy.csv']))
```

[image]

Click on choose file located directory of your file

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading files on drive first.
Then read.
Go to file.
Copy path.
Try following code.

```
from google.colab import files
Upload= files.upload
Df= pd.read_csv("file_path_file_name")
df.head
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import local directory excel files directly in Google collab. You have to upload the excel file in the Collab directory and then you can import it.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Collab you have to upload it in sample_data folder. But the file will lost after you close it. Other alternatives are jupyter notebook where you can do everything in google collab but offline.

But if you want to use google collab here's where you need to upload

```
Files >> sample_data >> upload files
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading files on drive first. Then read. Go to file. Copy path. Try following code according to  mu method in then below

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

after that:

```
df= pd.read_csv("copy path file here")
```